# How to display content of text file named with current date using java program

Tags: java, web-applications, cmd

I am working on a web application in which it takes action log for every minute i.e.., any action performed will be appended into a text file with current date as its name and if no action performed then it will append current time stamp in that same file. So for everyday one new file will be created and action performed will be appended in that file for that whole day. What I want now is, all those files are present in D:\ -->(presentdate)<--.txt and when I give a particular date in the same format as that of  file name in the "text field" and click on submit in my web application it has to show that file present in D drive as a hyper link(if present in the drive) and when I click on the hyperlink it should simply show the content in that file. I want to know how to search for a file in particular folder/drive without mentioning file name directly but searching for files which are having file names in specific format(Example: 27_06_2014.txt).Any suggestions will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String path = "D:" + File.pathSeparator + fileSearched + ".txt";

File f = new File(path);

if(f.exists()) {

        //do your stuff

}

//I dont know why would you like to search them as a list but anyways

File dir = new File("D:");

dir.mkdir();

for(String s : dir.list()){
     if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(fileSearched)){
         //do your stuff
     }
}
```

Here's the documentation for the [java.io.File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my web application, I have taken action log for every minute my application gets started. As I mentioned above every day it will create one text/log file and appends whole info into that file for that day. SO I am including the option to see what action is being performed every minute in the application to the user. Here I used text field and submit button and if user enters the date and submits it should retrieve that days file and show the content.

Comment: @user3364490 ok, I read it the first time you post it. There's your answer.

Comment: In the code snippet given above, if(f.exists()) { //how to display the content of that file in the html/jsp page??? }. What will this code do?
File dir = new File("D:");

dir.mkdir();

for(String s : dir.list()){
     if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(fileSearched)){
         //do your stuff
     }
}

Comment: @user3364490 read the documentation given above. As for the "How to display the content..." part, here's a tutorial for you: http://www.jsptut.com/

Comment: Thank you. This helped me in solving the problem. I have used File.seperator. I am unaware of this method before so I raised a question. Thanks for helping me.